# Excel macro - to open multiple external files to delete few rows (not continous rows)

Tags: excel, csv, xlsx, vba

I am looking for a macro which will allow me to select multiple excel/CSV files from any source (will specify that by browsing).

Once all the files are selected this macro will need to delete certain rows. I have already done this. But struggling with the first part.

Any idea?

Thanks
Leo

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please note, that this is not a free code-writing service, but we are eager to help fellow programmers (and aspirants) writing their own code. Please read the help topics on [How To Ask a Good Question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask "How To"). You might also want to take the [Tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour "Magical Mystery Tour") and earn a badge while doing so. Afterwards, please update your question with the VBA code you have written thus far in order to complete the task(s) you wish to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

So you're looking for a way to have a user select multiple files, then loop through each of them and do some work, correct? You can use something like this:

```
Dim i As Integer
Dim strFiles() As String

With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker) 'Show the dialogue window
    .Title = "Select files" 'Set the title at the top of the dialogue
    .AllowMultiSelect = True 'Allow selection of multiple files
    .Filters.Add "Data files", "*.xls,*.xlsx,*.csv" 'Specify file types
    .Show 'Show the window

    If .SelectedItems.Count > 0 Then 'Make sure items were selected
        ReDim strFiles(1 To .SelectedItems.Count) 'Resize the array to store them
        For i = 1 To .SelectedItems.Count 'Loop through all selected items
            strFiles(i) = .SelectedItems(i) 'Copy the file name and path into the array
        Next i
    Else
         'If nothing was selected, exit the macro
         MsgBox "No files selected."
        Exit Sub
    End If
End With
```

You'll end up with an array, strFiles, that contains all the file names you want to use.